# Show product variations on WooCommerce archive pages as shop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

After a long search and a lot of trial and error I found the code below to display variable products in the shop and on the category page. After a small modification it works fine. But it also displays the variations in all categories, instead of only showing the variations of the current category.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_query_get_posts_by_date' );

// Modify the current query

function custom_modify_query_get_posts_by_date( $query ) {
 if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
           add_filter( 'posts_where', 'rc_filter_where' );
   }
     return $query;
 }
}

// Add products variation post type to the loop
function rc_filter_where( $where = '' ) {

   $type = 'product_variation';
   $where .= " OR post_type = '$type'";

   return $where;

}
```

I figured if I can limit the pre_get_posts to the current category that should work. Tried a lot of things, but I can't get it to work.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_query_get_posts_by_date' );

// Modify the current query

function custom_modify_query_get_posts_by_date( $query ) {
 if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

 if ( is_product_category() ) {
    $cate = get_queried_object();
    $cateID = $cate->term_id;

       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
       $query->set('cat', $cateID);
           add_filter( 'posts_where', 'rc_filter_where' );
   } elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) || is_product_tag() ) {
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
           add_filter( 'posts_where', 'rc_filter_where' );
   }
     return $query;
 }
}

// Add products variation post type to the loop
function rc_filter_where( $where = '' ) {

   $type = 'product_variation';
   $where .= " OR post_type = '$type'";

   return $where;
}
```

So I would like to know if it's possible to show all product variations in the shop and on the category view only show the variations that belong to that category.

Comment: I would have focus actually on the rc_filter_where . The " OR post_type =..." is the reason why the query ignores your category limitation and just display any post with that type, no matter what category or any other filter you want to add.

Comment: Thanks Shir Gans. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove the posts_where's and try tax_query instead of $query->set('cat', $cateID);?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_modify_query_get_posts_by_date' );

// Modify the current query

function custom_modify_query_get_posts_by_date( $query ) {
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()  && $query->is_tax('product_cat') ) {

if ( is_tax('product_cat')  ) {
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;
$cateslug = $cate->slug;
$catetax = $cate->taxonomy;

//$query->set('cat', $cateID); 

$taxquery = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => $catetax,
    'terms' => $cateslug,
    'field' => 'slug',
    'include_children' => true,
    'operator' => 'IN'
      )
    );

$query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );

$query->set( 'post_type', array('product', 'product_variation') );

   $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

} elseif ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) || is_product_tag() ) {
   $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

}
 return $query;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Nahum. I've tried that code, but it only displays the parent variation product. So the single variations aren't shown anymore.